# Twilio Response Class not found

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I am new to Twilio.  To learn the basics, I followed the instructions here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/click-to-call/php/laravel#12

At first, my phone would ring, and I would receive a generic message.  Impressed, I upgraded my account.  Now I receive a call where a voice says "We're sorry an application error has occurred."

I checked my Alerts in Twilio, and found **Error: 12100 - Document parse failure**

So I checked the url of my outbound.php and realized that there is a PHP error here.  The error is

> Fatal error: Class 'Response' not found in
>   /home/......./outbound.php on line 16

After some searching, I can't find anyone else discussing this same problem.  Finally, the worst part, I can't even find any reference to a Response class in the Twilio Helper Library.

Here is my entire code block for the page in question.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'twilio-library/Services/Twilio.php';


    // A message for Twilio's TTS engine to repeat
    $sayMessage = 'Thanks for contacting our sales department. If this were a 
        real click to call application, we would redirect your call to our 
        sales team right now using the Dial tag.';

    $twiml = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $twiml->say($sayMessage, array('voice' => 'alice'));
    // $response->dial('+12345675309');

    $response = Response::make($twiml, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    return $response;

?>
```

If I change this file to static, well formatted XML then the error stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The tutorial you were following was based within the [Laravel framework](http://laravel.com/), which is where the `Response` class was expecting to come from.

If you are using the PHP TwiML builder in just a plain PHP file, you should be able to just `print` the `$twiml`. I'd probably add a Content-Type of text/xml as well, just to be safe. Like this:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  require_once 'twilio-library/Services/Twilio.php';

  // A message for Twilio's TTS engine to repeat
  $sayMessage = 'Thanks for contacting our sales department. If this were a 
    real click to call application, we would redirect your call to our 
    sales team right now using the Dial tag.';

  $twiml = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
  $twiml->say($sayMessage, array('voice' => 'alice'));
  // $twiml->dial('+12345675309');

  header('Content-type: application/xml');

  print $twiml;
?>
```

Let me know if this helps at all!